# precontroller hooks in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, hook

I am using pre-controller hook codeigniter in my project

Description:
  we are using subdomain concept and three templates(theme). eg: My site is xyz.com. this is having one first template.

some business signup with this xyz site. for eg. abc(business). We create abc.xyz.com. abc chooses 2 template.  abc.xyz.com in browser need to show 2nd template. It is not showing 2nd template. it is showing only 1st template.

When we clicked any link on the site more than once , then the template 2 is set for abc.xyz.com link.

I am using codeigniter. loaded session, database in autoload files.

I used precontroller hook to check whether the url is xyz or any subdomain abc.xyz.com
In hook i am setting template if the url is subdomain one.

But template is not showing when abc.xyz.com is in browser. when i refresh the url for some clicks or clicked any of the header link some count , it showing the actual template of the business abc.

Please help me to fix this issue or provide me some solution .

```
<?php
class Subdomain_check extends CI_Controller{
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->CI =& get_instance();

    if (!isset($this->CI->session))
    {
    $this->CI->load->library('session');
    }

}
function checking()
{

$subdomain_arr = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']); //creates the various parts

if($subdomain_arr[0] == 'www')
{
    $subdomain_name = $subdomain_arr[1]; //2ND Part            
}
else
{
    $subdomain_name = $subdomain_arr[0]; // FIRST Part                      
}        

header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");   
header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Pragma: no-cache"); 

if( $subdomain_name != 'xyz' )
{
    $where = array();
    $where['subdomain_name'] = $subdomain_name;
    $where['status'] = 1;
    $this->db->from('subdomain_map');
    $this->db->where($where); 
    $query = $this->db->get();         
    if($query->num_rows() < 1)
    {
    header('Location:http://xyz.com/index.php?/error');
    }   
    else
    {
    $result = $query->row_array();
    $this->CI->session->set_userdata('subdomain_id',$result['subdomain_id']);
    $this->CI->session->set_userdata('subdomain_name',$result['subdomain_name']);
    $org_id = gat_organisationid_using_subdomainid($result['subdomain_id']);
    $this->CI->session->set_userdata('organisation_id', $org_id);

    if($org_id)
    {
    $templ_id = get_templid_using_organisationid($org_id);
    $org_logo = get_organisation_logo($org_id);
    }  

    if($templ_id){
    if($this->session->userdata('pinlogin'))
    $this->CI->session->set_userdata('template_set', 4);
    else
    $this->CI->session->set_userdata('template_set', $templ_id);               
    }

    if($org_logo)
    $this->CI->session->set_userdata('org_logo', $org_logo);              
    }           
}
else
{
    $this->CI->session->unset_userdata('subdomain_id');
    $this->CI->session->unset_userdata('subdomain_name');
    if( $this->CI->session->userdata('user_id') && $this->CI->session->userdata('user_category')<=2 )
    {
    $this->CI->session->unset_userdata('organisation_id');
    $this->CI->session->unset_userdata('org_logo');
    }
}    
}
```

}

Comment: how do you define what template to use? can you post your precontroller here?

Comment: provide more info (code) please.

Comment: The constructor code and your use of your extra CI-instance look very suspicious. Why would you need to get the CI instance with &get_instance() when you have the $this pointer, which in any controller is the same as &get_instance()?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic check you need to support custom themes per subdomain

```
// Gets the current subdomain
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
$host = explode('.', $parsedUrl['host']);

// store $host[0], which will contain subdomain or sitename if no subdomain exists
$subdomain = $host[0];   

// check for subdomain
if ($subdomain !== 'localhost' OR $subdomain !== 'mysite')
{
    // there is a subdomain, lets check that its valid
    // simplified get_where using activerecord
    $query = $this->db->get_where('subdomain_map', array('subdomain_name' => $subdomain, 'status' => 1));

    // num_rows will return 1 if there was a valid subdomain selected
    $valid = $query->num_rows() === 1 ? true : false;

    if($valid)
    {
         // set theme, user_data, etc. for subdomain.
    }
    else
    {
        // get user out of here with redirect
        header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/error');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Note that when using subdomains with codeigniter, you should set your config > base_url to the following:

`$config['base_url']    = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/poasty/poasty-starterkit/';`

this will ensure things like site_url() and other CI helpers still work.

Reading through your code may I suggest utilizing more of Codeigniters built-in functionality, for example your `__construct` function has a lot of un-necessary code:

**Original code**

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

    /**
    * CI already exists 
    * since this controller extends CI_controller, there is already and instance of CI available as $this.
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    */

    /**
    * duplicate check, CI checks if library is loaded
    * and will ignore if loaded already
    if (!isset($this->CI->session))
    {
        $this->CI->load->library('session');
    }
    */

    $this->CI->load->library('session');

}
```

**Optimized for Codeigniter**

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->CI->load->library('session');
}
```

I suggest reading up on the Codeigniter user_guide to better understand what codeigniter can do. @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/

I hope you find this helpful!